# How can I design a finite state machine that counts according to this sequence?

Tags: counter

[image]

when X is equal to 0

and

[image]

when X is equal to 1

I don't understand how to write the truth table. I understand that when X=1, it means that the machine counts in the following order: 1,3,2,6,4,C,8,9 and when X=0 it counts in the following order 9,8,C,4,6,2,3,1. But I really can't understand how to write the truth table when using D-flip-flop for example.

[edit]
Here's the final result
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Hi Diana! What have you tried so far? The question as posed is basically a "do my full work to solve this very specific problem", and since that is of little benefit to future readers or for your engineering knowledge, we are often hesitant to do that. Instead, please describe which part exactly you find challenging?

Comment: Don 't concentrate on the actual numbers. Analyze the data as a whole and see if you can detect a pattern. In this case the pattern is no too difficult to spot.

Comment: @Oldfart so, if we were to name the variables Q3,Q2,Q1,Q0, Qi=1 for the first state and the rest are 0 and for the second state Qi=Qi-1=1 and the rest are again 0 and i takes values from i=3,0

Comment: Last tip: A 4 output FSM does not mean you MUST build it with four registers. In this case I would take 8 registers and build the FSM from that. It makes the solution very simple, almost trivial. But your professor might see that as 'cheating'.

Comment: Notice that `X=1` simply *reverses* the sequence.

Comment: @Diana I'd probably start with a twisted ring Johnson counter with four sync Dflops. This provides the needed number of states. From these outputs, it's relatively trivial to work out the needed logic for each separate output. It breaks out into three stages: (1) twisted ring counter; and, (2) \$X\$ select logic modifications to the counter outputs; and, (3) four trivial gates to generate the four outputs. A simple mental scan of the twisted ring counter bits immediately provides the right combinations if you just lay out the table. If needed, I can provide some more thoughts as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A standard twisted ring Johnson counter generates the following sequence after reset (the table also shows your two output sequences under \$z=0\$ and \$z=1\$):

$$\begin{smallmatrix}\begin{array}{c|ccc}
\text{Counter}&z=0&z=1\\r\ s\ t\ u
&a\ b\ c\ d&a\ b\ c\ d\\
\hline
0\ 0\ 0\ 0&1\ 0\ 0\ 1&0\ 0\ 0\ 1\\
1\ 0\ 0\ 0&1\ 0\ 0\ 0&0\ 0\ 1\ 1\\
1\ 1\ 0\ 0&1\ 1\ 0\ 0&0\ 0\ 1\ 0\\
1\ 1\ 1\ 0&0\ 1\ 0\ 0&0\ 1\ 1\ 0\\
1\ 1\ 1\ 1&0\ 1\ 1\ 0&0\ 1\ 0\ 0\\
0\ 1\ 1\ 1&0\ 0\ 1\ 0&1\ 1\ 0\ 0\\
0\ 0\ 1\ 1&0\ 0\ 1\ 1&1\ 0\ 0\ 0\\
0\ 0\ 0\ 1&0\ 0\ 0\ 1&1\ 0\ 0\ 1\end{array}\end{smallmatrix}$$

Just look over this table, carefully. What do you see when you look it over?

For example, look at column \$a\$ underneath \$z=0\$. There are three \$1\$'s in that column. Under what conditions, looking at the bits under \$\text{Counter}\$ are uniquely constant? Do you notice that this is only when \$t=0\$ and \$u=0\$? So this implies either a NOR gate or else and AND gate using \$\overline{s}\$ and \$\overline{t}\$. (Both are equivalent here.)

Now look at column \$a\$ underneath \$z=1\$. There are also three \$1\$'s in that column. Under what conditions, looking at the bits under \$\text{Counter}\$ are uniquely constant? Do you notice that this is only when \$r=0\$ and \$u=1\$? So this implies either a NOR gate using \$r\$ and \$\overline{u}\$ or else and AND gate using \$\overline{r}\$ and \$t\$. (Again, both are equivalent here.)

Repeat the above process for each of the remaining columns (\$b\$, \$c\$, and \$d\$) found under \$z=0\$ and \$z=1\$ to generate a table of inputs and operations. If you do this, you should readily find that you can use a fixed gate type for each of the outputs (you have some flexibility about which fixed gates you choose to use.) Once that's been established, all you need to do is to work out the intermediary logic that depends upon \$x\$, which modifies the inputs arriving at these final gates.

I find that one XOR and two 2-in muxes are all that is needed in the middle.

---

There are other approaches, of course. You don't have to approach things the way I just did. There are other kinds of counters you can use to produce the eight states and therefore different resulting logic. But a twisted ring Johnson counter is a reliable counter and I think a good choice to use as the foundation for the rest.

Comment: @Diana You're welcome. I'm just glad it may have been some help.

Comment: @Diana If you want to see the design I'd have come up with, it's [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pYP2P.png).

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to try to answer your question as you asked it rather than suggest something completely different than what you want to do. I will outline a general design approach for this kind of sequential circuit.

You will need one truth table for each flip-flop. The inputs to the truth table are the **outputs** of **all** flip-flops as well as the X input. The **entries** in the truth table cells are the desired next state for the given flip-flop. The output of the combinational block that you design with this truth table will be connected to the D input of the flip-flop.

Analyze each flip-flop separately and design the combinational logic for each flip-flop's D input independently. Once you become more comfortable with this technique you will start to see simplifications, but you should begin with the basic brute-force technique.

Answer (score -2):

Depends on how fast you want it to respond, but if you can handle slowish just use a programmed memory chip. The address lines take the input and the output is whatever you programmed into it.

Comment: Not sure why this is downvoted. I have used this method several times in the past.